# Add many "p" tags

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery, I wish to know how to add many `<p>` tags under one `<div>` tag. Actually, I have this code :

```
   <body>
        <div id="clickMe"> Click here to change text </div>
        <div id="addFrame">
            <p> You didn't click yet. </p>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("document").ready(function(){
                $("#clickMe").click(function(){
                    $("#addFrame").add("p").text("Oh, you clicked !");
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
```

I want to click on the `clickMe` div and add many `<p>` tags under my `addFrame` div, thus, This HTML :

```
        <div id="addFrame">
            <p> You didn't click yet. </p>
        </div>
```

Will become after clicking something like this :

```
        <div id="addFrame">
            <p> Oh, you clicked ! </p>
            <p> Oh, you clicked ! </p>
        </div>
```

In order to achieve that, I tried this :

```
          $("document").ready(function(){
                $("#clickMe").click(function(){
                    $("#addFrame").add("p").text("Oh, you clicked !");
                    $("#addFrame").add("p").text("Oh, you clicked !");
                });
            })
```

But only one `p` is added.

Is there some function (tried appendTo() as well, adds just one) I am not aware of that's able to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually mean `append()`, not `add()`. `append()` will add new nodes to the document, while `add()` is just concerned with selecting additional items.

The following two lines are identical, and will select the `#addFrame` element, as well as all `<p>` nodes in the document - but won't actually do anything with any of them.

```
$('#addFrame').add('p')
$('#addFrame, p');
```

By using `<p>` instead of `p`, you'll create a new node instead of selecting all existing paragraphs in the document. I can't think of any reason you'd ever want to do that with `add()` though, since you'd just be selecting the `#addFrame` node plus a newly-created invisible (not in the document) paragraph.

Your primary problem, though, is coming from the fact that the `text()` call was being applied to the `#addFrame`, not the newly-created `<p>`.

You can create the `<p>` and set the text like this:

```
$('<p>').text('Oh, you clicked')
```

...and then put the whole thing inside an `append()` call:

```
$('#addFrame').append($('<p>').text('Oh, you clicked'));
```

Alternately, you could use `appendTo()` which is called on the child instead of the parent:

```
$('<p>').text('Oh, you clicked').appendTo('#addFrame')
```

Comment: One thing though, in this code : I think `add` should be replaced by `append`.

Comment: In fact, to use `add` the code should go : `$('#addFrame').add($('p').text('Oh, you clicked'));`, not : `$('#addFrame').add($('<p>').text('Oh, you clicked'));`. `add` will replace the sub-tree under the `#addFrame` div, while `append` will add to it (or append to it, as its name indicates).

Comment: Thanks @Gloserio. I've updated my answer to address that, and to emphasize the difference between `add`/`append`, and `<p>`/`p`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: `$('#addFrame).append($('<p>').html('Oh, you clicked !'))`

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the "why" of this question, you should be able to do:

```
$("#addFrame").append($("<P>").text("Oh, you clicked !"));
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8Bx/

Comment: The actual problem was that the `text()`  call was being applied to the `#addFrame`, not the newly-created `<p>`. Everybody's throwing code around without actually explaining this.

Comment: @jcsanyi : you just answered a question I was going to ask ;)

Comment: They've got the right answer - but I'd much prefer to see it explained properly. @Gloserio Pay special attention to the nested brackets in this answer.

Comment: @jcsanyi Add that as a new answer to the question, it certainly adds to the site even if it doesn't directly help the questioner?

Comment: @AdrianWragg : I don't have a use case, I am just testing code to learn. Indeed, his answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a for loop (after clearing out your "host" `div`, of course):

```
$("#addFrame").html(""); // clears the contents of #addFrame

for(var i = 0; i < number_of_ps_to_insert; ++i) {
  $("#addFrame").append("<p> something </p>");
}
```

Which appends that element as many times as you want to the target.

[Here's a jsFiddle that shows a live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/CT22r/)